# eclipse on mac: replace dialog - shortcut for replace all action

Tags: eclipse, macos, keyboard-shortcuts

coming from windows, I'm used to fire actions on dialogs by keyboard
(hitting alt, looking for underlined characted, pressing that one)

what should I press to fire the replace-all action once my text-search dialog is open?
milion thanks

Comment: Have you enabled full keyboard navigation in Universal Access?

Comment: I've got Full Keyboard Access checked, that means I can press 10x Tab to reach the Replace All button. Or could it help me in any another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fastest "shortcut" for me so far: 3x shift + tab, then space (with Full Keyboard Access enabled)

Answer (score 1):

Try pressing alt (key located between Ctrl and command) + a

Comment: Nope, alt + a just writes an "å" in the "Find" input field.